# Unity 5.4 Graphics API for windows Direct3D12 Doesn't activate

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine, directx-12

I work now with Unity 5.4.0f2 on a win10 computer with a GTX980ti and a 4700K i7 processor in it.

I filled the Direct3D12 option in the "Graphics APIs for Windows" section as only option, but the game returns automatically to the Direct3D11 API.

I checked it with the `SystemInfo.graphicsDeviceType`command.

How can I force the game to take DirectX12?

[image: picture]

Comment: Try running a simple DirectX 12 sample to make sure your system is setup correctly. See [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples)

Comment: I added the picture